# PyQt5で他のプロセス中に別ウィンドウでgif画像を表示したい

Tags: python, pyqt5

PyQt5で計算を行っている最中、別ウィンドウを開きgif画像を表示したいです。

Calculatingボタンを押すと、関数calcを実行している間、別ウィンドウが開きgif画像が表示されるように書いたつもりです。しかし、実際には表示された別ウィンドウではgifが全く動きません。ちなみに、Openボタンを押すと同じ別ウィンドウが開きますが、此方ではgifはしっかりと動きます。Closeボタンでは別ウィンドウが閉じます。

どうすればCalcuatingボタンを押したときでもgif画像が動くようになるのでしょうか。

---

**表示されるGUI**

[image: 画像]

**ソースコード**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import*
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
import time
from time import sleep

class Second(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)
        #Setting a title, locating and sizing the window
        self.title = 'My Second Window'
        self.left = 200
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 500
        self.height = 500
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("計算中")

        self._gif = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        movie = QtGui.QMovie("calculating.gif")
        self._gif.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()

        layout1=QVBoxLayout()
        layout1.addWidget(lbl)
        layout1.addWidget(self._gif)
        self.setLayout(layout1)
        #print("a")

class First(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)
        self.title = 'My First Window'
        self.left = 100
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 500
        self.height = 500
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Calculation", self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
        self.openButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Open", self)
        self.openButton.clicked.connect(self.open_newWindow)
        self.closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Close", self)
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.close_newWindow)        

        self.newWindow = Second()

        layout=QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.openButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.closeButton)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.newWindow.show()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        j = self.calc()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        self.newWindow.close()
        print("the result of calculation is",j)

    def calc(self):
        j = 0        
        for i in range(100000000):                
            j += i
        return j   

    def open_newWindow(self):
        self.newWindow.show()

    def close_newWindow(self):
        self.newWindow.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = First()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんな感じで計算を別スレッドにすれば動きます。

- `import threading`して`calc()`メソッドを別スレッドで実行する
- 単純な戻り値は取得出来ないので、戻り値を受け取る変数をパラメータで渡し、値を入れる
  関連記事[Return value from thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1886090/9014308) の承認付きの[Queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue) 経由でもよいが、こちらの[回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34132917/9014308) が簡潔で良さそう
- スレッド実行中かどうかチェックし、実行中は`QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()`を呼ぶ
  完了待ちは`timeout`を指定してチェックループ内で行う(ループ後の無限待ちでも良いが)

import部分

```
import threading  # 追加
```

処理の変更部分を抽出してコメント

```
def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
    self.newWindow.show()
    QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
    result = {'retVal': -1}    # ここから計算処理関連の変更
    tcal = threading.Thread(target=self.calc, args=[result])
    tcal.start()
    while tcal.is_alive():
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        tcal.join(timeout=0.001) # ここまで変更箇所

    self.newWindow.close()
    print("the result of calculation is", result['retVal']) # 戻り値の表示

def calc(self, result): # 戻り値パラメータ追加
    j = 0
    for i in range(100000000):
        j += i

    result['retVal'] = j # 戻り値の設定
    return               # return では値を返さない
```

Answer (score 0):

`PyQt5.QtCore.QThread` を使う方法もあります。以下に改変したコードを記載しますが、`First` クラス内に `QThread` クラスを継承する `CalcThread` クラスを追加しています。計算終了後、`My Second Window` を閉じます(実際には非表示(`hide()`)にしています)。

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout 

class Second(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)
        #Setting a title, locating and sizing the window
        self.title = 'My Second Window'
        self.left = 200
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 500
        self.height = 500
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel("計算中")

        self._gif = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        movie = QMovie("calculating.gif")
        self._gif.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()

        layout1=QVBoxLayout()
        layout1.addWidget(lbl)
        layout1.addWidget(self._gif)
        self.setLayout(layout1)

class First(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)
        self.title = 'My First Window'
        self.left = 100
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 500
        self.height = 500
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton("Calculation", self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
        self.openButton = QPushButton("Open", self)
        self.openButton.clicked.connect(self.open_newWindow)
        self.closeButton = QPushButton("Close", self)
        self.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.close_newWindow)        

        self.newWindow = Second()

        layout=QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.openButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.closeButton)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        ## Calculation thread
        self.calc_th = self.CalcThread(self.calc, self.calc_done)

    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.newWindow.show()
        self.calc_th.start()

    def calc(self):
        j = 0        
        for i in range(100000000):                
            j += i
        self.calc_result = j   

    def calc_done(self):
        self.newWindow.hide()
        print('The result of calculation is ', self.calc_result)

    def open_newWindow(self):
        self.newWindow.show()

    def close_newWindow(self):
        self.newWindow.close()

    class CalcThread(QThread):
        def __init__(self, task, task_done):
            QThread.__init__(self)
            self.task = task
            self.task_done = task_done

        def run(self):
            self.task()
            self.task_done()
            self.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = First()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```